# Money over time

Tags: percentages

If I invest $1000$ dollars, I make $10$% of that on day one.
The next day I take the amount I had plus the profit, and invest it making $10$% of that.
How can I calculate the amount it will be after $100$ days ?
I know the formula for a 10 percent increase of static $1000$ dollars a day.
$1000 * 1.1^{100}$
But that is not the formula I need.

Comment: What do you tink the result should be after two days? What would you get from $\$1000 \times 1.1^2$?

Comment: $S_0*(1+r)^t$ **is** the formula you need, the one for *compound* interest. For "static" sum (*simple* interest) the formula is $S_0*(1+tr)$, $1000*(1+100*0.1)$ for your numbers.

Comment: Will try that, Thanks !

Comment: [$1000\times\left(\frac{110}{100}\right)^{100}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1000%5Ctimes%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B110%7D%7B100%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B100%7D)

Comment: The formula you show is the compound interest formula.  It is exactly the formula you need.

Comment: An investment that promises 10% yield _per day_? Run away as fast as you can; with utter certainty it will be some kind of scam, and you will never see the money you invested again.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: be optimistic: risk 1 cent and get $12,833,055,803,133.- after a year if no scam.